# Creating an abstract generic method

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, abstract-class

I have a C# class with a method such as below:

```
public class MyType
{
    public MyType Clone()
    {
        var clone = (MyType)MemberwiseClone();

        // Do some other stuff here with the clone's properties

        return clone;
    }
}
```

I have a bunch of other classes where I want to implement the Clone method so I was thinking I could create an abstract base class where I could define the Clone method generically so I don't have to put a concrete implementation in each class.

I would think this is possible but I haven't worked too much with generics and my attempts to do this in the past (months ago, so discarded my code out of frustration) haven't been successful.

Is this possible? If so, how could it be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an abstract generic base and then implement the concrete type on the derived ones:

```
public abstract class ClonableBase<T>
{
    public T Clone()
    {
        return (T)this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}

public class RealClass : ClonableBase<RealClass> { }
```

Answer (score 2):

**The usefulness of this approach depends significantly on what it is that you're cloning.**

Here's a method that I use. The cloning method is a bit crude. It's specifically for objects that are meant to be serialized as JSON.

That's why the generic constraint (`TEntity : BaseEntity`) is there. I don't want just anything passed into this method, only something that I know is serializable.

I also avoided using the generic argument for `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` because while I want to cast the result as a specific type, I don't want to pass in an inherited type and get back an instance of a base type.

```
public static TEntity CloneEntity<TEntity>(this BaseEntity input) where TEntity 
    : BaseEntity
{
    if (input == null) return null;
    var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input);
    return (TEntity)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serialized, input.GetType());
}
```

Although it's already been accepted, I don't recommend adding this to a base class unless absolutely necessary. Before long you might find that you need to clone something that already inherits from a different base class.

This requires the [Newtonsoft.JSON](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) package.

As mentioned in a comment, this will do a deep clone. As I stated at the top, this method applies only if serialization/deserialization cloning is appropriate to the types you need to clone. If there were a universally applicable way to clone objects that applied in every case then `object` would probably have a public `Clone` method.

If we're cloning classes it's likely because they contain data, and where that's the case deep cloning is likely preferable. For example, suppose we have a `Customer` class, and one if its properties exposes an `Address` object. `MemberwiseClone` will clone the value types, but will result in two `Customer` objects that share a reference to the same `Address`. If we're cloning it's usually because we're trying to create entirely distinct objects. If we *think* we've cloned something but beneath the surface the original and clone share object references then there's a good chance we'll have bugs.

Comment: Serializing is a very heavy operation compared to MemberWiseClone. Also this will serialize even private fields and that's not the behavior that MemberwiseClone exposes.

Comment: @Gusman The question doesn't specifically state that OP wants to use MemberwiseClone. It might just be the only option he knows of. (And it might be the right one in this case.) Cloning using serialization is a common practice when it fits, and I included the caveat. I can't see downvoting something that may provide a useful alternative, even if it might not.

Comment: Wouldn't this do a deep clone in contrast to `MemberwiseClone`? @Gusman: In my understanding `MemberwiseClone` creates an exact shallow copy of the original object without distinction between private and public. This might not be the case for serializers

Comment: That's why I think the answer depends somewhat on knowing what's being cloned and why. The OP uses MemberwiseClone, but based on other aspects of the question might not know the alternatives. If someone wants a functionality across classes I'm very hesitant to recommend inheritance as the solution. It makes sense in some cases. But if the only commonality between these objects is that they need to be cloned then inheritance is probably a mistake.

Comment: @Olivier Jacot-Descombes Yes, sorry, you're right, it will copy the private fields but one is swallow copy and the other is deep copy, I'm a bit dizzy and my head doesn't works too well.

Comment: @Scott Hannen You're complaining about inheriting but you force in your code to inherit from a base... a bit nonsensic. Also, you're forcing the user to add a reference to json.net and you haven't even stated it in the answer. I have removed the negative but at least complete your answer noticing those two points, deep cloning and requirement to a nuGet package.

Comment: @Gusman Fair enough, I added some notes. The inherited classes used in my example involve base entities and inherited entities, which are a case where inheritance is more commonly used. Ironically, that class does have a clone method which was implemented incorrectly and I had just finished fixing the bug when I saw this question. If inheritance is already in place then I don't think it hurts to put it in an existing base class. It seems like some of the intent is to force developers to choose their cloning strategy because they need to know how it is implemented and what gets cloned or not.

Answer (score 0):

Built on @Gusman's solution I add the possibility to do some initialization

```
public abstract class ClonableBase<T>
{
    public T Clone()
    {
        T clone = (T)MemberwiseClone();
        Initialize(clone)
        return clone;
    }

    protected virtual void Initialize(T clone)
    {
    }
}
```

If the initialization is mandatory, you can also make `Initialize` abstract instead.

```
public class RealClass : ClonableBase<RealClass> {
    protected override void Initialize(T clone)
    {
        // Do some other stuff here with the clone's properties
    }    
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't be better to just make Clone virtual and override it if initialization is needed?

Comment: Yes, this is another option. You would then first call `var clone = base.Clone();`